# Spring Maven dependency issue during JUNIT

Tags: spring, maven

I'm Struggling to do junit to my code, I'm using spring 3.2.3, when I use spring 3.0.2 it working fine. This question is same as [Spring JUnit Test Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237181/spring-junit-test-error) but in the example he had said to use transitive dependency(which I don't understand what it is). what I understood from the answer is to exclude the older version of jars(resolved depenedency). However when I verified from dependency hierarchy I could find that all the dependency has resolved to version 3.2.3 and there are no older version of dependencies

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>artifact</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*local.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
   <testResources>
                  <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </testResource>
                  <testResource>
                    <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                      <include>**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                  </testResource>
                </testResources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

and the stack trace is.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoader(ContextLoaderUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:594)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:560)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.<init>(TestContext.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

As a novice guy to maven, can somebody help me out what exactly do I need to do

My Junit example class is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:spring-config.xml")
public class HelloWorldTest {


    @Autowired
    public HelloWorld hello1;

    @Test
    public void sayHelloTest(){
         hello1.printHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: `spring-test` dependency is not explicitly declared in your POM. Could you try adding it and see if it changes something ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had copied a wrong pom file. rectified it now

Comment: Your POM seems OK. Since you are running your test from Eclipse, I suspect a difference between dependencies declared in your POM and dependencies really used by Eclipse. You should check Eclipse project dependencies to see if it use Spring 3.2.3 everywhere. BTW using scope `provided` for Spring dependencies seems really odd. Scope `compile` should be better (except for `spring-test`, which must have scope `test`)

Comment: Where do I need to check, is it in Java build path/ Deployment Assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by checking whats the dependencies related to spring that was with an earlier version of the version of spring that I was using.

For example, I was using version 3.2.4 of spring and in my dependencies I found that the spring-beans and spring-expression were with version 3.0.4.
What I did was add these two to my pom.xml dependencies to the version of spring that I was using. in this case added

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId> org.springframework </ groupId>
   <artifactId> spring-beans </ artifactId>
   <version> ${spring.version} </ version>
 </ dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId> org.springframework </ groupId>
   <artifactId> spring-expression </ artifactId>
   <version> $ {spring.version} </ version>
 </ dependency>
```

and it worked.