# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I am trying to do the junit test for the spring jpa/hibernate application. while trying to run junit from eclipse i am getting below error. for junit i am using in memory database. Can anyone please help me to find the reason for this issue.

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>cricketapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cricketapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.9.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.27</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>cricketapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cricketapp.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cricketapp.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cricketapp.domain" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cricketapp" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>

     <bean  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"    id="entityManagerFactory">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cricketapp.domain" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>



    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"  id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 

</beans>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <import resource="classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>

 <bean  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"    id="entityManagerFactory">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cricketapp.domain" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:cricketapp" />
      <property name="username" value="sa" />
      <property name="password" value="" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

My Junit class

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class CricketAppServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    TeamService teamService;


    @Test
    public void testCreateTeam() {
    Team team = new Team();
    team.setName("RCB");
    teamService.createTeam(team);
    List<Team> retrievedTeam = teamService.getTeam();
    Assert.assertEquals(team.getName(),retrievedTeam.get(0).getName());
    }

    }
```

Error details

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [class org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:87)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:102)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:81)
    ... 20 more
```

Mvn dependency tree details

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] Building cricketapp Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO]
INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ cricketapp ---
INFO] com.mkyong.common:cricketapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:compile
INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.4.RELEASE:test
INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.9.Final:compile
INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA:compile
INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.9.Final:compile
INFO] |  |  \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27:compile
INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
INFO] \- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.2.8:compile
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError suggests that you may have some conflict of versions of your dependecies. Check if you do not have the same libs in different versions being loaded (they may be brought as transitive dependencies)

Comment: maven dependencies tree looks fine

Comment: Ok, so maybe one of your dependencies expects a different version of the lib, but maven fetches different one (because some other dep has in lower/higher version)

Comment: I have updated the question with maven dependency:tree details. I am getting is there any issue or not. for me it looks ok. Do you see any issue?

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237181/spring-junit-test-error

Comment: thanks nadir, this is due to version conflict. now its resolved. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I encountered this error while using the Eclipse IDE and fixed the error by correcting the JRE version used by my *Run Configuration*.